# Recover deleted IMAP e-mails

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, imap

IMAP mirrors the local machine with the mailserver. When e-mails are deleted on the server, they'll also disappear on the client. When this happens, is there any way to recover them within Microsoft Outlook 2010? Does it retain them in a local trash folder or somewhere?

From my searching, it looks like recovery is available at the push of a button if you're using a local Microsoft Exchange server. If you're not, is recovery impossible, or simply more difficult?

Comment: If the email isn't in the trash folder then there isn't much that can be done if its be removed from both the server and the local storage.

Comment: IMAP doesn't, by itself, mirror email messages. Normally, all clients simply view the same remote mailbox via the IMAP protocol. You may be able to configure local mail user agents (like outlook) to "mirror" server mail locally.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick - Thats what I thought.  Sounds like the author configured the email client to delete the remote email when its deleted though.

Comment: @Ramhound. Other way around. The e-mail was deleted from the server, and then also disappeared on the client. This would not have surprised me had I known the chap was using IMAP. He himself knew he was using IMAP, but thought (for some reason) that when we deleted e-mails on the server it would affect only his inbox, not his folders.

Comment: @TRiG - If it was deleted its gone.  IMAP only display a cache of the server.